# CakePHP 3.x - toArray() on null

Tags: php, cakephp, collections, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

In a controller method I'm trying to get the latest record in a table of revision comment history.

So I have this:

```
$RevisionSubstances = TableRegistry::get('RevisionSubstances');
$revision_history = $RevisionSubstances->find('all')->where(['substance_id' => $substance_id])->orderDesc('date')->first()-toArray();
debug($revision_history);
```

This works fine - as long as there are records in the `'revision_substances'` table which match the criteria.

I noticed that for queries where there is no matching data found (i.e. no records exist in the database matching the query) it gives me an error:

> Call to a member function `toArray()` on array

My workaround for this has been to remove `toArray()` from the query. I then used an `if` statement to check if `$revision_history` is not `null` before calling `toArray()` on it, like this:

```
$revision_history = $RevisionSubstances->find('all')->where(['substance_id' => $substance_id])->orderDesc('date')->first();

if ($revision_history) {
    $revision_history = $revision_history->toArray();
}
debug($revision_history);
```

This works and gives me the result I want - the output of `debug($revision_history);` is `null` and the application doesn't generate a fatal error.

Is this the correct/best way to handle this scenario or is there a more elegant way? I feel having to have an `if` statement is somehow un-necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `->first()` will return just one object, or null if there are none. `->toArray()` will convert an object to an array, if that's what you want, but you can't call a function on a null value, hence your error.

If you want an array returned directly from the `->first()` call, you could use `->hydrate(false)` earlier in the query, and then skip the `->array()` call.

You could also use `->firstOrFail()` and catch the resulting exception when there are no matching records; this is approximately equivalent to your `if` method, but might have benefits in certain cases.